# When using a RadioGroup, each object is one group how can it be seperated

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been working on a project and it seems that all of my Radio objects are associated one group and not separate entities. I have attempted to use 'rl.addView(rg)' in order to create a seperate group, but the application crashes on my phone. Any thoughts on how to get each question and answer as its own entity?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.android.masterofdreams;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quiz_view);

        // Initialize a new RadioGroup
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

        // Initialize the Layout parameters
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // Apply the layout parameters for RadioGroup
        rg.setLayoutParams(lp);


        // Create Question 1
        TextView rb_question_1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.addView(rb_question_1);

        // Create Question 1 RadioGroup

        rb_question_1.setText(R.string.question_1_textview);
        RadioButton rb_question_1_a = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_1_a.setId(R.id.answer_1a);
        rb_question_1_a.setText(R.string.answer_1_a);
        rb_question_1_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_1_a);

        RadioButton rb_question_1_b = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_1_b.setId(R.id.answer_1b);
        rb_question_1_b.setText(R.string.answer_1_b);
        rb_question_1_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_1_b);


        // Create Question 2
        TextView rb_question_2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.addView(rb_question_2);

        // Create Question 2 RadioGroup
        rb_question_2.setText(R.string.question_2_textview);
        RadioButton rb_question_2_a = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_2_a.setId(R.id.answer_2a);
        rb_question_2_a.setText(R.string.answer_2_a);
        rb_question_2_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_2_a);

        RadioButton rb_question_2_b = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_2_b.setId(R.id.answer_2b);
        rb_question_2_b.setText(R.string.answer_2_b);
        rb_question_2_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_2_b);

        // Create Question 3
        TextView rb_question_3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.addView(rb_question_3);

        // Create Question 3 RadioGroup
        rb_question_3.setText(R.string.question_3_textview);
        RadioButton rb_question_3_a = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_3_a.setId(R.id.answer_3a);
        rb_question_3_a.setText(R.string.answer_3_a);
        rb_question_3_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_3_a);

        RadioButton rb_question_3_b = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_3_b.setId(R.id.answer_3b);
        rb_question_3_b.setText(R.string.answer_3_b);
        rb_question_3_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_3_b);

        // Create Question 4
        TextView rb_question_4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.addView(rb_question_4);

        // Create Question 4 RadioGroup
        rb_question_4.setText(R.string.question_4_textview);
        RadioButton rb_question_4_a = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_4_a.setId(R.id.answer_4a);
        rb_question_4_a.setText(R.string.answer_4_a);
        rb_question_4_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_4_a);

        RadioButton rb_question_4_b = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_4_a.setId(R.id.answer_4a);
        rb_question_4_b.setText(R.string.answer_4_b);
        rb_question_4_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_4_b);

        // Create Question 5
        TextView rb_question_5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rg.addView(rb_question_5);

        // Create Question 5 RadioGroup
        rb_question_5.setText(R.string.question_5_textview);
        RadioButton rb_question_5_a = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_5_a.setId(R.id.answer_5a);
        rb_question_5_a.setText(R.string.answer_5_a);
        rb_question_5_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_5_a);


        RadioButton rb_question_5_b = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        rb_question_5_b.setId(R.id.answer_5b);
        rb_question_5_b.setText(R.string.answer_5_b);
        rb_question_5_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        rg.addView(rb_question_5_b);


        // Finally, add the RadioGroup to main layout
        rl.addView(rg);


        // Reviews quiz answers
        final RadioButton answer1A = findViewById(R.id.answer_1a);
        RadioButton answer1B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_1b);
        final RadioButton answer2A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_2a);
        RadioButton answer2B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_2b);
        final RadioButton answer3A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_3a);
        RadioButton answer3B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_3b);
        final RadioButton answer4A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_4a);
        RadioButton answer4B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_4b);
        final RadioButton answer5B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_5b);
        RadioButton answer5A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_5a);

        // Submit Button
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

        //Calculate Score
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@score is the initialized to 0
            int score = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (answer1A.isChecked()) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                if (answer2A.isChecked()) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                if (answer3A.isChecked()) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                if (answer4A.isChecked()) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                if (answer5B.isChecked()) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Final Score " + score + " out of 5.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                score = 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: Below is the relevant information: 

02-03 00:44:42.626 1768-1793/system_process W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@4f157ec does not ex